# How to continue training an object detection model using Tensorflow Object Detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-ml, object-detection-api

I'm using [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection#tensorflow-object-detection-api) to train an object detection model using transfer learning. Specifically, I'm using [ssd_mobilenet_v1_fpn_coco from the model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md#coco-trained-models), and using the [sample pipeline provided](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync.config), having of course replaced the placeholders with actual links to my training and eval tfrecords and labels.

I was able able to successfully train a model on my ~5000 images (and corresponding bounding boxes) using the above pipeline (I'm mainly using Google's ML Engine on TPU, if revelant).

Now, I prepared an additional ~2000 images, and would like continue training my model with those new images, without restarting from scratch (training the initial model took ~6h of TPU time). How can I do that?

Answer (score 8):

You have two options, in both you need to change the `input_path` of the `train_input_reader` of your new dataset:

1. When specifying a checkpoint to fine-tune in the training configuration, specify the checkpoint of your trained model

```
train_config{
    fine_tune_checkpoint: <path_to_your_checkpoint>
    fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
    load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: true
}
```

2. Simply keep using the same configuration (except the `train_input_reader`) with the same `model_dir` of your previous model. That way, the API will create a graph and will check whether a checkpoint already exists in `model_dir` and fits the graph. If so - it will restore it and continue training it.

Edit: fine_tune_checkpoint_type was previously set as true by mistake, while it should be "detection" or "classification" in general, and "detection" in this specific case. Thanks Krish for noticing.

Comment: Did you simply add more examples of classes already represented for did you introduce new classes? If new classes, what value did you use for num_classes: in the pipeline? Also, did you create a new classes.pbtxt file or simply append the new classes?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't retrained the object detection model on a new dataset, but it looks like
increasing the number of training steps `train_config.num_steps` in the config file and also adding images in the tfrecord files should be enough for that.