# Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.iter

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

So i was using the pre-trained weight from this link: http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz
then i copied the pipeline.config from the download link to my folder because **i want to change the optimizer to adam to train on my own dataset** (the pipeline in the link is using momentum_optimizer)

Here is my code for my pipeline.config to train:

```
optimizer {
adam_optimizer {
  learning_rate {
    cosine_decay_learning_rate {
      learning_rate_base: 0.01
      total_steps: 50000
      warmup_learning_rate: 0.026666
      warmup_steps: 1000
    }
  }
  epsilon: 1e-8
}
use_moving_average: false
```

}

**but then the cmd promt hit me with this**:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.iter
W0419 23:47:07.776149 17436 util.py:194] Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.iter
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.decay
W0419 23:47:07.777309 17436 util.py:194] Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.decay
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.momentum
W0419 23:47:07.779311 17436 util.py:194] Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.momentum
```

Can anyone explain please thank you
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBmVA.png

Comment: These messages simply warn you that the parameters iter, decay and momentum of the optimizer could not be restored from the checkpoint (because you changed the optimizer apparently).

Answer (score 2):

`model.load_weights(MY_CHECKPOINT_FILE).expect_partial()` has been working for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same mistake while executing the following lines:

```
python Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=Tensorflow\workspace\models\my_ssd_mobnet --pipeline_config_path=Tensorflow\workspace\models\my_ssd_mobnet\pipeline.config --num_train_steps=2000
```

Changing the number of steps worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was to go into the model checkpoints folder and deleting all the previous checkpoints, leaving only the pipeline config file there.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was to go into the model checkpoints folder and deleting all the previous checkpoints, leaving only the pipeline config file there.

Para mi si funciono esta manera, lo que haces es de que te vas a la carpeta de my_ssd_mobnet y eliminas los checkpoint y solo dejas el archivo pipline.config y corres el comando: python Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=Tensorflow\workspace\models\my_ssd_mobnet --pipeline_config_path=Tensorflow\workspace\models\my_ssd_mobnet\pipeline.config --num_train_steps=2000

Comment: You should use english in your response.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all of the earlier checkpoints, and that works just fine for me. You can alter the checkpoint's path as well.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33348977)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53104638/13546426) answer, we need to increment `train_config.num_steps` and also `train_config.optimizer.momentum_optimizer.learning_rate.cosine_decay_learning_rate.total_steps` for the optimizer to work correctly. If the previous checkpoints were trained with `num_steps=30000`, you should increment `num_steps` to `50000` (any number greater than `30000`).

```
train_config: {
  ...
  num_steps: 50000 <--- Increment the steps here
  ...
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          ...
          total_steps: 50000 <--- Should be equal to `num_steps`
          ...
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when you load your weights the state of the optimizer is not being loaded, as shown in [this][1] thread. So as its said there - just add `.except_partial()` at the end of your loading statement, e.g.:

```
model.load_weights(checkpoint_file).expect_partial()
```

Cheers
[1]: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43554#issuecomment-748820652

Answer (score 0):

From Tensorflow docs:

> Loading from SavedModel checkpoints
>
> To load values from a SavedModel, just pass the SavedModel directory
> to checkpoint.restore:
>
> ```
> model = tf.keras.Model(...)
> tf.saved_model.save(model, path)  # or model.save(path, save_format='tf')
>
> checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(model)
> checkpoint.restore(path).expect_partial()
> ```
>
> This example calls expect_partial() on the loaded status, since
> SavedModels saved from Keras often generates extra keys in the
> checkpoint. Otherwise, the program prints a lot of warnings about
> unused keys at exit time.

source: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint#restore